# $f$ Continuously differentiable twice on $[0, 1]$, $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{(f(x)-1)^2-4x^2}{x^\frac{7}{2}}dx$ converges, calculate $f(0), |f'(0)|$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

> Let $f$ be a function that is continuously differentiable twice on $[0, 1]$ such that 
>   $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{(f(x)-1)^2-4x^2}{x^\frac{7}{2}}dx$ converges.
>
> Calculate $f(0), |f'(0)|$
>
> *Note: we can use the fact that if $f$ is continuous on $[0, 1]$ and there exists $p \geq 1$ such that $\int\limits_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{x^p}dx$ converges
>
> then $f(0)=0$

I used the note and found that $f(0)=1$, but I'm not sure how to find $|f'(0)|$

I thought about trying to use L'Hôpital together with the limit convergence test but it didn't work out.

I'm just looking for a hint on how to approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$$ f(x)=1+f'(0)x+O(x^2)$$
and then
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\frac{(f(x)-1)^2-4x^2}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}\\
&=&\frac{(f'(0)x+O(x^2))^2-4x^2}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}\\
&=&\frac{(f'(0)+O(x))^2-4}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
&=&\frac{(f'(0))^2-4+O(x)}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}
\end{eqnarray}
If $(f'(0))^2-4=0$ or $|f'(0)|=2$, then
$$\frac{(f(x)-1)^2-4x^2}{x^{\frac{3}{2}}}=O(x^{-\frac12})$$
and hence
$$ \int_0^1\frac{(f(x)-1)^2-4x^2}{x^{\frac{7}{2}}}dx $$
converges.

Comment: shouldn't it be $O(x)$ instead of $O(x^2)$?

Comment: Should be $O(x)$ since $(f'(0)+O(x))^2=(f'(0))^2+2f'(0)O(x)+O(x)^2=(f'(0))^2+O(x).$

Comment: i mean at the beginning, where you write $f(x)=1+f′(0)x+O(x^2)$, it should be $f(x)=1+f′(0)x+O(x)$ instead

Comment: Should be $O(x^2)$ instead of $O(x)$ since it already has $f'(0)x$.

Comment: Can you explain? If we would use lagrange remaider we would have remainder of order n=1, so it should be o(x), where am i wrong?

Comment: I understand now, I was thinking about small o notation, we didn't study big O.
I think the solution still works with small o as i suggested though right?

Comment: You are right. Little o works too.